# VBA using Instr on date/time cells not consistent

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of date/times and I'm using InStr to find me the times I'm looking for, cells in Excel look like so: 19/07/2016  10:55:00 AM

Here I'm looking here for anytime between 12:00 - 12:59 AM:

```
If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, " 12:") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "AM") > 0 Then
```

I have this scan through 50 documents. It works for the first 28 and on the 29th document (which has similar data) it returns 0.

I have also had documents where I successfully search for " 12:", " 1:", "2:" etc. but when I seach " 7:3" it returns 0.

```
ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, " 7:3") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "AM") > 0 And ActiveCell.Row > Leq730Row + 600 Then
```

But again, with some documents it returns this successfully and others it doesn't.

Do I have to specify time format before I start reading the data? When I open the excel the files look the same, but I feel like I'm not understanding how VBA reads the cell.

Comment: @ScottCraner Is it possible to make it search as a text string? It's working accurately for all of the other documents this way.

Comment: If you want to work with a cell's *text*, then use its `.Text`, not its `.Value`. But why work with strings at all when you're looking at dates?

Answer (score 1):

Time is stored as a decimal so three options:

First use the decimal instead of text:

```
ElseIf ActiveCell.value mod 1 >= 0 and ActiveCell.Value mod 1 <= 1/24 And ActiveCell.Row > Leq730Row + 600 then
```

Or you can reference the text of the cell:

```
ElseIf InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, " 12:") > 0 And InStr(1, ActiveCell.Text, "AM") > 0 And ActiveCell.Row > Leq730Row + 600 Then
```

Or you can use Format on the value to make it a string text:

```
ElseIf InStr(1, Format(ActiveCell.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"), " 12:") > 0 And InStr(1, Format(ActiveCell.Value, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"), "AM") > 0 And ActiveCell.Row > Leq730Row + 600 Then
```

Comment: Use the decimal portion of the `Date` value. The rest is working with dates *as strings*, which is a paved road to insanity IMO ;-)

Comment: Formatting fixed the first part of my problem, thanks! Still working on the 7:30, there are fewer errors but still errors.

Comment: @M.Daly are you sure it is `7:3` and not `07:3` try `" 07:3"`

Comment: @M.Daly or change the format to `""dd/mm/yyyy h:m:s AM/PM"`

Comment: FWIW: this why changing all dates to true date values and not text that looks like a date/time is easier to deal with than text. @M.Daly